# how do I control a camera from Java?

Tags: java, camera

As I am building an application for a project I am working on, I am at a cross roads.  I am researching trying to find an API used for controlling camera functionality from Java.  JMF is dead, and this is not going to run on a windows platform.  I've looked into DSJ, but not running it on a windows platform sort of negates running it.  I've also seen some examples that are supposedly grabbing the camera output, but it was grabbing the desktop, and not working, and using Java AWT / Swing is not what I am trying to do either.  This is not an android based project either or I would use the API's for that.

My thoughts are #1 - does ANYONE know of a suitable framework in java that would allow the programmatic control of a camera and perhaps servos(optional)? and #2 - If java is java, could I simply import the android packages used for controlling a phone camera?

It might be a little clearer if I try to explain what I am trying to do.  I have 2 ODroid-X boards that I am trying to run Ubuntu on and cluster together.  Either I want to write an application to run across an Apache Tomcat cluster running on them, or write an in depth application using Open-MPI and set it up in a true cluster.

The ultimate goal is to convert my RC plane into a UAV.  I know there are some out of the box solutions, but none fit my application and I am starting to think I understand why...

Any information on getting a camera to work with Java would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Warmest Regards,

Josh

Comment: consider using other languages. Silverlight / WCF / Flash has native support of camera source.

Comment: You will probably have to use JNI, unless of course there's some framework out there that's already done it... http://lti-civil.org/ looks ok although the FPS may be a problem for you..

Comment: @Thihara FPS isn't important to me.  I'm looking for (at the moment) go to this way-point take a x pictures, transmit them back to the ground station.  Took a look at lit-civil.org.  7fps@160x120?!?!?  Maybe if I was using windows... man what a drag.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, [Jitsi](http://www.aosabook.org/en/jitsi.html) does it like this:

> [...] there are things that the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) does not support or does not do the way we'd like it to, such as capturing video from your webcam. Therefore, we need to use DirectShow on Windows, QTKit on Mac OS X, and Video for Linux 2 on Linux.

Not very encouraging, but since it's open source, you could take a look at how they did it.

Comment: I started looking into the Oracle ME SDK, there is some hinting on that being able to do it since it is for more embedded devices.  If not there, then I need to see if the android sdk would work and just write the project using that.  I know that the ME is designed for more ARM architectures though.